# Prevent fixed elements from jumping on input focus in Mobile Safari

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I'm running into a relentless fixed position bug in Safari. I'm on iOS9 but I've noticed it in iOS8 as well. To reproduce the problem (example link below):

1. position fixed element over the entire screen
2. fill it with enough content – including a form with several inputs – so it's scrollable
3. set overflow scroll
4. open it in mobile Safari
5. scroll down until you see the first input and tap it to focus
6. scroll a bit more and focus the next one (and notice the elastic looking jump)
7. scroll a bit more and focus the next and keep going. The more inputs you focus the more insane the jump gets.

Example: http://jsbin.com/zaruba/edit?html,css,output

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

`user-scalable=0` is not valid.

From [Safari development library](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html), supported Meta Tags:

> user-scalable
>
> Determines whether or not the user can zoom in and
> out—whether or not the user can change the scale of the viewport. Set
> to yes to allow scaling and no to disallow scaling. The default is
> yes. Setting user-scalable to no also prevents a webpage from
> scrolling when entering text in an input field.

Comment: That's what I have it set to and the problem persists. Thanks for trying to help though.